# How to send text from screen1 to screen2, using i.putExtra?

Tags: android, class, button, android-intent

I'm writing a recipe book, and I've encountered a problem - I want to send text from my recipe list to recipe display screen, and I must be doing something wrong because I keep getting force closes:

This is code for my Recipe_Button_List

public class Recipe_Button_List extends Activity {

EditText inputMethod;

EditText inputIngredients;

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.recipe_button_list);

    inputMethod = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    inputIngredients = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);



    Button mainNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Recipe1);
    mainNext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            mTextView.setText(R.string.Test);
            Intent i= new Intent(getBaseContext(),recipedisplayscreen.class);
            //Sending data to the next screen
            i.putExtra("textView1", inputIngredients.getText().toString());
            i.putExtra("textView2", inputMethod.getText().toString());

            Log.e("n", inputMethod.getText()+"."+ inputIngredients.getText());

            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
     inflater.inflate(R.menu.recipe_menu1, menu);
     return true;

}
```

}

And this is my recipe_display_screen:

public class recipedisplayscreen extends Activity {

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.recipedisplayscreen);

    TextView MethodDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    TextView IngredientsDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    String Ingredients = i.getStringExtra("TextView1");
    String Method = i.getStringExtra("TextView2");
    Log.e("recipedisplayscreen", Ingredients + "." + Method);

    MethodDisplay.setText(Method);
    IngredientsDisplay.setText(Ingredients);


    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    setTitle(R.string.title);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);}

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                // App icon in action bar clicked; go home
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainScreen.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }




 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.recipe_menu1, menu);
        return true;

}
```

}

Here are records from logCat:

05-01 21:54:54.638: D/AndroidRuntime(10717): Shutting down VM
05-01 21:54:54.638: W/dalvikvm(10717): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a301f8)
05-01 21:54:54.638: E/AndroidRuntime(10717): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-01 21:54:54.638: E/AndroidRuntime(10717): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bluStudios.Recipes4U.ics/com.bluStudios.Recipes4U.ics.Recipe_Button_List}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
05-01 21:54:54.638: E/AndroidRuntime(10717):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
05-01 21:54:54.638: E/AndroidRuntime(10717):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
05-01 21:54:54.638: E/AndroidRuntime(10717):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
05-01 21:54:54.638: E/AndroidRuntime(10717):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
05-01 21:54:54.638: E/AndroidRuntime(10717):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-01 21:54:54.638: E/AndroidRuntime(10717):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-01 21:54:54.638: E/AndroidRuntime(10717):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
05-01 21:54:54.638: E/AndroidRuntime(10717):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-01 21:54:54.638: E/AndroidRuntime(10717):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-01 21:54:54.638: E/AndroidRuntime(10717):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-01 21:54:54.638: E/AndroidRuntime(10717):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-01 21:54:54.638: E/AndroidRuntime(10717):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-01 21:54:54.638: E/AndroidRuntime(10717): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
05-01 21:54:54.638: E/AndroidRuntime(10717):    at com.bluStudios.Recipes4U.ics.Recipe_Button_List.onCreate(Recipe_Button_List.java:25)
05-01 21:54:54.638: E/AndroidRuntime(10717):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
05-01 21:54:54.638: E/AndroidRuntime(10717):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
05-01 21:54:54.638: E/AndroidRuntime(10717):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
05-01 21:54:54.638: E/AndroidRuntime(10717):    ... 11 more

PS Force close happens when I press the button that takes you to the recipe_button_list

**EDIT:**
Hi again :)
I've got another small problem - my recipe_display_screen recieves null.null form my previous screen any idea why?

LogCat:

05-02 11:28:29.764: D/dalvikvm(28455): GC_CONCURRENT freed 113K, 2% free 14526K/14727K, paused 2ms+14ms
05-02 11:28:30.022: E/n(28455): FromStringMethod.if this is displaying then Intent activity is working correctly
05-02 11:28:30.163: D/dalvikvm(28455): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1769K, 13% free 12813K/14727K, paused 23ms
05-02 11:28:30.163: I/dalvikvm-heap(28455): Grow heap (frag case) to 13.883MB for 1401676-byte allocation
05-02 11:28:30.202: D/dalvikvm(28455): GC_CONCURRENT freed 3K, 4% free 14179K/14727K, paused 2ms+2ms
05-02 11:28:30.218: E/recipedisplayscreen(28455): null.null

**EDIT END**

Comment: When does it force close? Can you get us a (preferably filtered by app) logcat?

Comment: Did you declare both of your activities in your AndroidManifest.xml file? This is a frequent mistake I see...

Comment: I added logcat to my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah! you're casting textviews to edit boxes. See the lines

```
inputMethod = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
inputIngredients = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

change them to

```
inputMethod = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
inputIngredients = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

and change the declarations of inputMethod and inputIngredients.

Unless you meant them to be EditTexts, in which case you need to change that in your layout recipe_button_list

Comment: Yeah, I suddenly thought of that... but assumed that the xml would be right and not the code... but either or

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**
In your Logcat you cast a TextView to an EditText. Set the view in your XML-layout-file to an EditText and it has to work :)

```
inputMethod = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
inputIngredients = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

**EDIT-END**

you put your data in your first activity:

```
Intent i= new Intent(this, recipedisplayscreen.class);
//Sending data to the next screen
i.putExtra("textView1", inputIngredients.getText().toString());
i.putExtra("textView2", inputMethod.getText().toString());
```

in RecipeDisplayScreen you can fetch data in your `onCreate()`

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

String myText1;
String myText2;


if(extras != null) {
   if (extras.containsKey("textView1") {
      myText1 = extras.getString("textView1");
   }
   if (extras.containsKey("textView2") {
      myText2 = extras.getString("textView2");
   }
}
```

I hope it works for you! If not, please post your Log-Output :)

Some tips:
think for good key names and set them as constans:

```
public static final String INGREDIENTS_KEY = "INGREDIENTS_TEXT_KEY";
public static final String METHOD_KEY = "METHOD_TEXT_KEY";
```

Use for class name ALWAYS capitals
`recipedisplayscreen` => `RecipeDisplayScreen`
For fields use small letters:
String Method => String txtMethod;
`TextView MethodDisplay` => `TextView methodView;`

Comment: thanks for tips :P haha I'm still new to programming :) , I'll let you know if this works tommorow, as I have to go now :P thanks for help

Comment: THANK YOU - I've been stuck with this one for quite a while :P its working perfectly thank you :D